# Using remote file as attachment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to pull a public AWS file and use it as an attachment, like so:

```
attachments['file.zip'] = open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip')
```

I'm getting a `No such file or directory`

I've changed the paths above to be generic, but I can indeed navigate to the AWS path and get a file. Is there a way to make it an attachement for use by ActionMailer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
attachments['file.zip'] = open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip').read
```

`open` returns an IO object, not the content of the file. You must give the file content to [`attachments`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-attachments).

Comment: Oh, I skipped the error message. You may need to `require 'open-uri'`

Comment: I get `undefined method 'ascii_only?'` when doing this

Comment: Worked for me, thank you for taking the time to reply.